# Is there any way to add 'custom' legend in R ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there any way to add a truly 'custom' legend in R ggplot2?

All instructions available online seem to only introduce ways to modify the already existent legends from the original data.

Is it possible to add a custom legend, in any shape and and words, that do not exist in the original dataset?

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kG3g.png)

```
data.frame(x = 1:5,
y = rnorm(5),
z = c('a', 'b', 'c' , 'd' , 'e')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + geom_point()
```

for example, if I run the code

it gives the above image.

What I would like to do is, add a circle filled with 'red' color that has 'ABCDE' legend, which is nonexistent in the original dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are different ways to do this. One way to achieve you concrete goal would be to make z a factor with 'abcde' as a factor level (which does not appear in the data) and then use `drop == FALSE` in the color scale.

```
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = rnorm(5), z = c('a', 'b', 'c' , 'd' , 'e')) 
dat$z <- factor(dat$z, levels = c(letters[1:5], 'abcde'))
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, color = z)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(rep("black",5), "red"), drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

And a second option would be to add an additional category via the `limits` argument of the color scale, where for the latter I use `scale_color_manual` as in the approach by @AndreasM:

```r
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = rnorm(5), z = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, color = z)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(rep("black", 5), "red"),
    limits = \(x) c(x, "abcde")
  )
```

[image]